# Is rollback possible in Database-project?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, sql-server-data-tools, database-project

I have created database project in visual studio 2013 from existing database. Then I have done lot of changes in database project like modify stored procedures, post deployment script, table structure, etc . Now database project is ready to deploy. But I am worry if any script fails then How I can retain the original state though it build properly.

Please suggest that if any query fails then I want ROLLBACK the all changes that I have made in database project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you been checking your changes into version control? If so, all you need to do is to revert back to the last known good version.

Or... simply work out why it's failing now and fix the root cause?

Comment: Unfortunately that is not exactly correct. If you schema changes include removal of data (e.g. dropping a column) than this answer would not address this and the data stays lost after reverting to a previous version. A backup strategy must be included in this case, so Ed Elliot's answer is more appropriate I think.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly you need to trust your tools and either believe they will work or find other tools.

While you are building the trust I would add a create backup to the pre-deployment script or run a backup before you deploy then if anything goes wrong you can restore and figure out what went wrong.

As David said to roll-back, you would get the previously deployed dacpac and generate a new deployment script from that *but* fixing forward is almost always the correct thing to do rather than rolling back to a previous version.

ed

Answer (score 2):

I used Db projects some time ago and as far as I remember the deploy script was wrapped in a transaction. It is possible to generate sql script without executing it. That setting was somewhere in DB project settings. You can take a look inside that script and make sure that it'll rollback on error.

Doing a backup would still be a recommended practice especially when you deploy to production.

Comment: There's an option to wrap it in a transaction. If you disable that, there's no transaction. It also won't apply to post-deploy scripts.  Generally speaking, if there's an error when trying to change the schema through the project and you have the transaction option enabled, it will roll back the changes on error.

Comment: At the time of deployment of .dacpac file Rollback option is available. But the time of publish it won`t be. Is it by default rollback?

And one more How rollback is work in case of DML commands.

Comment: The publish command uses whatever you tell it to do. If you tell it to wrap the changes in a transaction, it will do so. That's one of the options. Rollback for data scripts will need to be handled separately, though.

Answer (score 0):

when working on important scripts I developed a habit of always starting a transaction and commenting out the commit.
If you accidentally run it, it won't take effect. The commented out commit would only come out when the thing was done.
While this answer indicates that you CAN revert in source control (Assuming SSDT at this point) it would be nice to get a pointer to the exact process to do this. On a file by file basis the history works the same but how to revert the entire database at once isn't immediately obvious.